# Query Facebook for a user's birthday?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Using the PHP sdk I'm signing users into my site with Facebook log in.  I've requested the birthday and "any time access" permissions.  Having forgotten to grab the birthdate at initial signup, how can I grab the user's birthday?  As far as I understand the "any time access" permission would permit this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=birthday&access_token=[access token here]" to find a persons birthday.

You can then use PHP to add this to a database or do whatever with it